# Saving multiple images

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I have a list with meshgrid matrices.
After I plot these I want to safe each of them with a different name.

```
game = []
start = []

while len(game)<=1000:
    m = np.random.randint(0,3,(5,5))
    m[random.randint(0,4)][random.randint(0,4)] = 4

    num_zeros = (m == 0).sum()
    num_ones = (m == 1).sum()
    num_twos = (m == 2).sum()
    if num_ones ==9 and num_twos ==8:
        game.append(m), start.append(1)
    elif  num_ones ==8 and num_twos ==9:
        game.append(m)
        start.append(2)

num_zeros , num_ones, num_twos
```

I am trying this after plotting

```
colors = ['lightcyan','#6871E4','#E67CCC', 'black']


for i in range(len(game)):
    plt.matshow(game[i],cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors)) #[0,1,2,4])
    plt.title('start', color = colors[start[i]],fontsize = 22)
    for i in range(5):
        plt.axhline(i+0.5, c = 'azure', linewidth=11)
    for i in range(5):
        plt.axvline(i+0.5, c = 'azure',linewidth=11) 
    plt.axhline(-0.5, c = 'azure', linewidth=11)
    plt.axvline(-0.5, c = 'azure', linewidth=11)
    plt.axvline(4.55, c = 'azure', linewidth=5)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.savefig('game'+str(i)+'.png')
```

As a result I only get image 4 saved xD

Thanks!

Comment: `for i in range(5)` uses the same `i` as in the outer loop. Python does not have that kind of variable scoping. With a few exceptions (involving fancy stuff like nested functions), it's just local vs global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the loop variables of your inner ( nested ) loops. Something like this :

```
colors = ['lightcyan','#6871E4','#E67CCC', 'black']


for i in range(len(game)):
    print(i)
    plt.matshow(game[i],cmap=mpl.colors.ListedColormap(colors)) #[0,1,2,4])
    plt.title('start', color = colors[start[i]],fontsize = 22)
    for j in range(5): #change i to j
        plt.axhline(j+0.5, c = 'azure', linewidth=11)
    for k in range(5): #change i to k
        plt.axvline(k+0.5, c = 'azure',linewidth=11) 
    plt.axhline(-0.5, c = 'azure', linewidth=11)
    plt.axvline(-0.5, c = 'azure', linewidth=11)
    plt.axvline(4.55, c = 'azure', linewidth=5)
    plt.axis('off')
    print("saving"+'game'+str(i)+'.png')
    plt.savefig('game'+str(i)+'.png')
```

Now your inner loops wont over-write the actual value of `i` with which you are saving images.